# kubectl jsonpath command to list out failed jobs and namespaces

Tags: kubectl, jsonpath

The command below give a list of failed jobs

```
kubectl get jobs -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.failed==1)].metadata.name}' --all-namespaces
job-3764289372 abc-23145263524 xyz-6745096523
```

I need to list out the jobs and their namespaces. Is it possible to do this with jsonpath?
Something like below?

```
NAMESPACE                  NAME
dev-namespace              job-3764289372  
namespace-123              abc-23145263524
```

Comment: Hey, did the following answer helped you ? if yes, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible using plain `jsonpath` and a post processing(*solution-2*) is needed. However, if you could use `go-template`(*solution-1*), then it can be done with `go-template` without using any post processing.

```
k get job
NAME   COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job1   1/1           2m36s      3h27m
job2   0/1           3h23m      3h23m #failed
job3   0/1           3h23m      3h23m #failed
```

**Solution-1:** using `go-template`:

Below `go-template` will print the namespace and name of the failed `job`.

```
kubectl  get job -A  -o go-template='{{range $i, $p := .items}}{{range .status.conditions}}{{if (eq .type "Failed")}}{{$p.metadata.namespace}} {{$p.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
default job2
default job3
```

**Solution-2:** using `jsonpath` with `awk`.

```
 kubectl get job -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace} {.metadata.name} {.status.conditions[*].type}{"\n"}'|awk 'BEGIN{print "namespace","name"}$NF=="Failed"{print $1,$2}'
namespace name
default job2
default job3
```